# How to pass information from a form to a form on another page?

Tags: javascript

I have a start page where the user enters Name and Mail. When I click on the button, I just get a redirect and the user is transferred to another page. This page contains a complete registration form, where the two fields Name and Mail are already filled with the information that the user entered on the first page. How can I implement this functionality?

```js
// Form submit function
const regForm = document.getElementById("reg-form");
if (regForm) {
  form.addEventListener("submit", formSend);

  async function formSend(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData(form);

    let response = await fetch("../sendmail.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((formData) => {
        window.location.href = "../thanks.html";
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
}
```

```html
//START PAGE

<form action="./registration.html">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon name"></div>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" value="" required="true">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon email"></div>
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" value="" required="true">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <button class="button subscribe green" type="submit">Go to next page!</button>
  </div>
</form>

//REGISTRATION PAGE

<form id="reg-form" action="./sendmail.php">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon name"></div>
        <input class="form-control req" data-val="true" data-val-length-max="45" data-val-length-min="1" name="firstname" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="" required="true" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon name"></div>
        <input class="form-control req" data-val="true" data-val-length-max="45" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="" required="true" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon email"></div>
        <input class="form-control email req" data-val="true" data-val-length-max="255" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" value="" required="true" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="input-group group-phone">
        <input class="js-phone form-control req" data-val="true" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone" type="tel" minlength="7" required="true" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 ">
      <button type="submit" class="button signup subscribeBtn" name="submitBtn">Start</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: 1. save name & email in localstorage before redirecting and read the same once registration page loads. 2. redirect with query params and read the same once registration page loads.

Comment: Would be good to use wizard form for that, there are a lot of javascript wizard you can check or see https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp